# How to apply ThemedTk themes to Notebook Frames?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Below is the code I have. The theme is not applied to any notebook tabs, as shown in the screenshot below. How to fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk


root = ThemedTk(theme="smog")
root.title("Lipid Analysis GUI")
#style = ThemedStyle(root)
#style.set_theme("breeze",themebg='black')
note = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
tab4 = Frame(note)
note.add(tab1, text = "Merge")
note.add(tab2, text = "TAG/Plot")
note.add(tab3, text = "Read mzml")
note.add(tab4, text = "PC/Plot")
note.pack()
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6tZ1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the standard tk `Frame` widget which doesn't use the themes provided by ttktheme. If you want your tabs (or perhaps more accurately, the frames used to make the tabs) adhere to the theme, you need to use `ttk.Frame` rather than `Frame`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.